How can I repeat first elements on wrap in a flex layout?
I have a number of sequences. Each sequence have a name and an array of characters. I have to order the characters vertical aligned:
sequence1 AGCAGTAGACAGTAGTACGTACGATAGCTCGACTAGCA
sequence2 GCGTAGCTCAGCTTCGATCCGATCGATATAAAGCTAGA
sequence3 GCTTCGGAGCGGCTAGCTAGAGATAGCCGATCGATCGA

If the character arrays becomes longer (or the visible space is small), line breaks occurs and i want the following display:
sequence1 AGCAGTAGACAGTAGTACGTACGATAGCTCGACTAGCA
sequence2 GCGTAGCTCAGCTTCGATCCGATCGATATAAAGCTAGA
sequence3 GCTTCGGAGCGGCTAGCTAGAGATAGCCGATCGATCGA
sequence1 GGATTAGCTAGCTAGACTACGGATCGA
sequence2 GGAGGATCGGCTTCGATCGATTCTTAG
sequence3 GGCATTTAGGGGGATTATATTTCTCTA

The length of sequences can be very high. It is neccessary to repeat the sequence names.
How can i achieve that?


.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.stack {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: courier;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="stack">
        <div>Sequenz1</div>
        <div>Sequenz2</div>
        <div>Sequenz3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>c</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>t</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>g</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div>a</div>
    </div>
</div>



If I resize the window. Flex wraps like expected. But I need the names again.

Have you tried adding flex-wrap: wrap to the .stack class?

@Ortrud: stack should not wrap

For a general solution I think you are going to need JS. Is that acceptable? (A CSS/HTML solution given below, but that works only for 3 sequences, as given in the question, and the number of repeated blocks is set in the shadow repeats - up to 20 in the example given).

@AHaworth: Actually i created the container with vue. But i thought, the calculation of line-breaks in JS is more complex then using CSS.

I certainly wouldn't calculate line breaks in JS, but in order to have a general solution I believe you will need some JS just to make things practical, otherwise there's a lot of stuff to be typed into the CSS. (ie I was suggesting JS to create the CSS).

Understood. Perhaps vue can handle this in an elegant way. I will dig a little deeper.

What is the largest set of stuff you will need to deal with in practice? Number of sequences and longest possible string? [I'm wondering if it's so huge browsers might struggle?]

The JS needed to create the text-shadow is very simple, I've added it, and made things a bit more general, to my answer. It would be good if you could do a test on some real, large data.

To get a fully scalable system I think you'd need JS [see below], but here is a CSS/HTML only method which repeats the labels using text-shadows, having separated them out from the text strings using grid.
And I guess if this is DNA where you may have millions of characters it's not going to be very practical.
Given here more as a fun demo for anyone who has a less huge problem.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.seqences {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.labels {
  text-shadow: 0 3lh 0px black, 0 6lh 0px black, 0 9lh 0px black, 0 12lh 0px black, 0 15lh 0px black, 0 18lh 0px black, 0 21lh 0px black, 0 24lh 0px black, 0 27lh 0px black, 0 30lh 0px black, 0 33lh 0px black, 0 36lh 0px black, 0 39lh 0px black, 0 42lh 0px black, 0 45lh 0px black, 0 48lh 0px black, 0 51lh 0px black, 0 54lh 0px black, 0 57lh 0px black;
}

.stack {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: courier;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="stack labels">
    <div>Sequenz1</div>
    <div>Sequenz2</div>
    <div>Sequenz3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seqences">
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Here is the version with simple JS needed to create the text-shadow depending on the number of sequences (which it can find out for itself) and the maximum number of repetitions you will need (which you have to tell it). The version here has set that to 400 just for a test, but I don't have a real set of sequences to test it with.


// set n to the maximum number of block repetitions you are ever going to need (if the system can cope!)
const n = 400;
const labels = document.querySelector('.labels');
const s = labels.children.length;
let t = '';
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  t += '0 ' + i * s + 'lh 0 black,';
}
t = t.slice(0, -1);
labels.style.setProperty('--t', t);
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.seqences {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.labels {
  text-shadow: var(--t);
}

.stack {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: courier;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="stack labels">
    <div>Sequenz1</div>
    <div>Sequenz2</div>
    <div>Sequenz3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="seqences">
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>g</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>g</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>c</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>t</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>t</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>c</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>g</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="stack">
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Using grid then flex is interesting. It would be great, if css grid creates new rows...

Why do you want new rows? I actually think nothing extra being added to the DOM is what is wanted here - especially for accessibility you don't want those labels to be actually repeated in the DOM, they are just a visual clue, and the line breaks are just to make things visible within the viewport they have no semantics attached to them. Is there something about showing such sequences that I haven't taken into acount?

I've added a version with JS creating the text-shadow to get the labels 'repeated' to make it easier for larger sequences and the system now works out how many sequences there are for itself.

Now tested up to 10,000 repetitions of the labels (created as text-shadows) and, to  my surprise, the system (Edge. Win10) coped if scrolling was taken not too frantically,. You may need to throttle scrolling whatever method you choose with such long strings regardless of how you eventually show the repeated label text.

That work's! I implemented it in my vue-code.
It's for educational purpose. So the lengths of sequences are not very high. I will try it with longer sequences.

I have no scrollbars anymore. :-(

What are you wanting to scroll? Move the overflow: hidden from .container to ,labels - but I don't know what you are trying to achieve so can't really offer proper advice.

There was an error in my surrounding div. All OK. Thank you.
